# How to disable multiple buttons in nativescript with typescript

Tags: typescript, nativescript

I'm new to nativescript and typescript. I have a card app that I want to be able to pick 6 cards out of 20 but each card can only be picked once. How do I disable the individual buttons after that have been clicked once?

The card numbers are put into an array and that is working fine. If I continue to click the same button it will continue to add it to the array. I would also like to disable the Submit button until the six cards are picked then enable. I did this in a PHP/jQuery webpage and it was very simple. I have played around with some of the solutions I have found here to disable buttons, but they either haven't worked or the button was just disabled all the time.

```
***main-page.xml***
<Button text="Card 0" value="0" tap="{{ pickCard }}" class="btn btn-card" />
<Button text="Card 1" value="1" tap="{{ pickCard }}" class="btn btn-card" />
<Button text="Card 2" value="2" tap="{{ pickCard }}" class="btn btn-card" />
...
<Button text="Get my results" tap="{{ onTap }}" class="btn btn-primary btn-active" />

***main-view-model.ts***
private _counter: number;
private _ids: number[] = new Array();

    pickCard(args) {
        var cardValue = args.object.value;

        if (this._counter <= 5) {
            this._ids.push(cardValue);
            this._counter++;
        }

        if (this._counter == 6) {
            /* Enable Submit button */
        }
    }
```

I was trying to make this lightweight so I thought I would use typescript rather than vue or angular. I know very little about vue/angular/typescript and thought typescript would be the best option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a ObservableArray, bind it's length to `isEnabled` attribute of Button.

**XML**

```
<Button text="Tap 6 times" class="btn btn-primary" isEnabled="{{ items.length, items.length < 6 }}" tap="{{ addItem }}"></Button>
```

import { Observable } from 'tns-core-modules/data/observable';
import { ObservableArray } from 'tns-core-modules/data/observable-array';

**ViewModel**

```
export class HomeViewModel extends Observable {

    items: ObservableArray<any> = new ObservableArray([]);

    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    addItem() {
        this.items.push(Date.now());
    }
}
```

[Playground Sample](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-tsc&id=NMhOfa)

Comment: Not what I'm looking for, there will be 20 buttons plus the submit. The user will pick 6 different buttons and is only allowed to click a button once. But thanks for the **isEnabled** that did help me figure out the submit button being enabled after selecting 6 of the card buttons. `isEnabled="{{ _ids.length, _ids.length > 5 }}"`